# Alternative to CSV?

Tags: rest, csv, plaintext

I intend to build a RESTful service which will return a custom text format.  Given my very large volumes of data, XML/JSON is too verbose.  I'm looking for a row based text format.

CSV is an obvious candidate.  I'm however wondering if there isn't something better out there.  The only I've found through a bit of research is [CTX](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Std/ctx/ctx.htm) and [Fielded Text](http://www.fieldedtext.org/).

I'm looking for a format which offers the following:

- Plain text, easy to read
- very easy to parse by most software platforms
- column definition can change without requiring changes in software clients

Fielded text is looking pretty good and I could definitely build a specification myself, but I'm curious to know what others have done given that this must be a very old problem.  It's surprising that there isn't a better standard out there.

What suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that since CSV is the standard, and since everyone under the sun can parse it,  use it.

If I were in your situation, I would take the bandwidth hit and use GZIP+XML, just because it's so darn easy to use.

And, on that note, you could always require that your users support GZIP and just send it as XML/JSON, since that should do a pretty good job of removing the redundancy accross the wire.

Comment: Or rather, no one under the sun can parse it.

Comment: Could you please show me the official spec for csv. How to encode unicode? How to quote a comma in csv files? How to encode binary data like PDF/PNG in csv?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you've already considered this, but I'm a fan of tab-delimited files (\t between fields, newline at the end of each row)

Comment: Could you please show me the official spec for this. How to encode unicode? How to quote a tab in tab-delimited files? How to encode binary data like PDF/PNG in tab-delemited files?

Comment: @guettli It known as [tab-separated values (TSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values).

Answer (score 4):

You could try YAML, its overhead is relatively small compared to formats such as XML or JSON.

Examples here: http://www.yaml.org/

Surprisingly, the website's text itself is YAML.

Comment: AFAIK YAML is not tabular. Every row can have different attributes/columns.

Comment: @guettli It could be said that YAML is a superset of tabular formats, as everything which can be stored in CSV can also be stored in YAML. The opposite is of course not true. (example: https://gist.github.com/noirotm/e2eaa5f40a346910901285584dca75c2)

Comment: YAML has a ton of issues, this is discussed [here](https://noyaml.com/) in detail. The Implicit conversion of "NO" to boolean for example (could also mean Norway.)

Answer (score 2):

I have been thinking on that problem for a while. I came up with a simple format that could work very well for your use case: JTable.

```
 {
    "header": ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"],
    "rows"  : [
                ["aaa", "xxx", 1],
                ["bbb", “yyy”, 2],
                ["ccc", “zzz”, 3]
              ]
  }
```

If you wish, you can find [a complete specification of the JTable format](https://www.settlenext.com/jtbl/), with details and resources. But this is pretty self-explanatory and any programmer would know how to handle it. The only thing necessary is, really, to say, that this is JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the existing answers, most struck me as a bit dated. Especially in terms of 'big data', noteworthy alternatives to CSV include:

- ORC : 'Optimised Row Columnar' uses row storage, useful in Python/Pandas. Originated in HIVE, optimised by [Hortonworks](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_performance_tuning/content/hive_perf_best_pract_use_orc_file_format.html). Schema is in the footer. The Wikipedia entry is currently quite terse  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ORC but Apache [has a lot of detail](https://orc.apache.org/).
- [Parquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet) : Similarly column-based, with similar compression. Often used with Cloudera Impala.
- [Avro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Avro) : from Apache Hadoop. Row-based, but uses a Json schema.  Less capable support in Pandas. Often found in Apache Kafka clusters.

All are splittable, all are inscrutable to people, all describe their content with a schema, and all work with Hadoop. The column-based formats are considered best where cumulated data are read often; with multiple writes, Avro may be more suited. See e.g. https://www.datanami.com/2018/05/16/big-data-file-formats-demystified/

Compression of the column formats can use SNAPPY (faster) or GZIP ([slower but more compression](https://newbedev.com/spark-sql-difference-between-gzip-vs-snappy-vs-lzo-compression-formats)).

You may also want to look into Protocol Buffers, Pickle (Python-specific) and Feather (for fast communication between Python and R).